# Windows Phone App Memory Consumption

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am developing app for Windows Phone. My application is a little game for children which is based on silverlight animation. In app I can navigate to 1 to 3 pages and when  the whole game logic completed It again goes to the start screen at the end of game and you can start again. When I complete 3 or four rounds, I saw that my application is consuming more than 80 MB (or more) of Phone RAM. Is there any chances of app rejection from Windows Phone app store if it is consuming such amount of memory???

Answer (score 1):

For Low memory devices, the maximum memory limit for a Silverlight app is 90MB for WP7 and 150MB for WP8.

So, your app may run into performance issues as the no of rounds progresses.

I think you are aware of the Performance analysis tests in Visual Studio, if not check this : [Techniques for memory analysis of Windows Phone apps](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Techniques_for_memory_analysis_of_Windows_Phone_apps)

And you can follow the suggestions mentioned here : [App performance considerations for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967560%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: But I want to know why this happens? If my app is running for long time why it is adding it;s memory footprint as the time goes?? Is there could be any memory leakage, if yes then what are the things which could cause memory leakage in windows phone????

Comment: Those 2 links given in my answer should guide you in the right direction. Check them.